# Heat map by city in R?

Tags: r, maps, ggmap

I have a dataframe of most of cities in California, and the median price of rent per sqft of that city. My goal is to create a heat map by city that is similar to this:

[image]

All examples I have seen are either divided by states, or counties, so I am wondering if it's possible to do a heatmap by cities in R, either by package `maps` or `ggmap`.

Reproducible dataframe:

```
structure(list(city = structure(c(181L, 168L, 109L, 135L, 18L, 
23L, 124L, 185L, 49L, 174L, 165L, 80L, 114L, 137L, 153L, 97L, 
154L, 8L, 193L, 43L, 67L, 164L, 107L, 142L, 149L, 21L, 79L, 46L, 
204L, 192L, 39L, 195L, 189L, 216L, 61L, 131L, 117L, 15L, 211L, 
44L, 115L, 35L, 38L, 176L, 72L, 25L, 105L, 134L, 2L, 199L, 178L, 
123L, 104L, 167L, 74L, 19L, 209L, 116L, 163L, 184L, 3L, 170L, 
152L, 57L, 121L, 146L, 139L, 112L, 27L, 130L, 68L, 53L, 213L, 
128L, 119L, 106L, 147L, 77L, 16L, 91L, 93L, 194L, 41L, 47L, 175L, 
155L, 190L, 198L, 37L, 99L, 31L, 177L, 1L, 200L, 171L, 129L, 
71L, 166L, 70L, 76L, 143L, 28L, 20L, 84L, 26L, 127L, 102L, 62L, 
158L, 126L, 191L, 88L, 140L, 22L, 98L, 50L, 42L, 169L, 186L, 
180L, 51L, 87L, 141L, 12L, 5L, 65L, 95L, 14L, 69L, 182L, 86L, 
133L, 206L, 188L, 205L, 78L, 101L, 159L, 29L, 6L, 58L, 217L, 
92L, 122L, 10L, 17L, 172L, 150L, 183L, 145L, 179L, 214L, 48L, 
52L, 201L, 36L, 138L, 210L, 89L, 208L, 63L, 56L, 148L, 125L, 
66L, 120L, 24L, 7L, 162L, 160L, 90L, 73L, 215L, 196L, 157L, 75L, 
96L, 203L, 60L, 108L, 100L, 151L, 136L, 187L, 30L, 212L, 34L, 
4L, 103L, 144L), .Label = c("Agoura Hills", "Alameda", "Albany", 
"Alhambra", "American Canyon", "Antioch", "Arcadia", "Atherton", 
"Auburn", "Azusa", "Bakersfield", "Baldwin Park", "Bell Gardens", 
"Bellflower", "Belmont", "Belvedere", "Benicia", "Berkeley", 
"Beverly Hills", "Brentwood", "Brisbane", "Burbank", "Burlingame", 
"Calistoga", "Campbell", "Carlsbad", "Carson", "Cerritos", "Chula Vista", 
"Citrus Heights", "Claremont", "Clearlake", "Cloverdale", "Colfax", 
"Colma", "Compton", "Concord", "Coronado", "Corte Madera", "Costa Mesa", 
"Cotati", "Covina", "Culver City", "Cupertino", "Cypress", "Daly City", 
"Danville", "Davis", "Del Mar", "Diamond Bar", "Downey", "Duarte", 
"Dublin", "Dunsmuir", "East Palo Alto", "El Cajon", "El Cerrito", 
"El Monte", "El Segundo", "Elk Grove", "Emeryville", "Encinitas", 
"Escondido", "Fairfax", "Fairfield", "Folsom", "Foster City", 
"Fremont", "Garden Grove", "Gardena", "Gilroy", "Glendale", "Glendora", 
"Half Moon Bay", "Hawaiian Gardens", "Hawthorne", "Hayward", 
"Healdsburg", "Hercules", "Hermosa Beach", "Hillsborough", "Hollister", 
"Huntington Park", "Imperial Beach", "Industry", "Inglewood", 
"La Canada Flintridge", "La Habra", "La Mesa", "La Mirada", "La Palma", 
"La Verne", "Lafayette", "Lakeport", "Lakewood", "Lancaster", 
"Larkspur", "Lemon Grove", "Livermore", "Lodi", "Lomita", "Long Beach", 
"Loomis", "Los Altos", "Los Altos Hills", "Los Angeles", "Los Gatos", 
"Lynwood", "Malibu", "Manhattan Beach", "Manteca", "Martinez", 
"Maywood", "Menlo Park", "Mill Valley", "Millbrae", "Milpitas", 
"Modesto", "Monrovia", "Montebello", "Monterey Park", "Moraga", 
"Morgan Hill", "Mountain View", "Murrieta", "Napa", "National City", 
"Newark", "Norwalk", "Novato", "Oakland", "Oakley", "Oceanside", 
"Orinda", "Pacifica", "Palmdale", "Palo Alto", "Paramount", "Pasadena", 
"Petaluma", "Pico Rivera", "Piedmont", "Pinole", "Pismo Beach", 
"Pittsburg", "Pleasant Hill", "Pleasanton", "Pomona", "Portola Valley", 
"Poway", "Rancho Cordova", "Rancho Palos Verdes", "Redondo Beach", 
"Redwood City", "Richmond", "Rio Vista", "Rocklin", "Rohnert Park", 
"Rosemead", "Roseville", "Ross", "Sacramento", "San Anselmo", 
"San Bruno", "San Carlos", "San Diego", "San Fernando", "San Francisco", 
"San Gabriel", "San Jose", "San Leandro", "San Marcos", "San Marino", 
"San Mateo", "San Pablo", "San Rafael", "San Ramon", "Santa Clara", 
"Santa Clarita", "Santa Fe Springs", "Santa Monica", "Santa Rosa", 
"Santee", "Saratoga", "Sausalito", "Sebastopol", "Sierra Madre", 
"Simi Valley", "Solana Beach", "Sonoma", "South Pasadena", "South San Francisco", 
"St. Helena", "Suisun City", "Sunnyvale", "Temecula", "Temple City", 
"Thousand Oaks", "Tiburon", "Torrance", "Tracy", "Truckee", "Ukiah", 
"Union City", "Vacaville", "Vallejo", "Vernon", "Vista", "Walnut Creek", 
"West Covina", "West Hollywood", "West Sacramento", "Whittier", 
"Windsor", "Woodland", "Woodside", "Yuba City"), class = "factor"), 
    count = c(67L, 1160L, 1L, 81L, 218L, 45L, 489L, 15L, 2L, 
    265L, 33L, 7L, 104L, 153L, 9L, 21L, 297L, 16L, 2L, 12L, 122L, 
    51L, 33L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 62L, 37L, 25L, 13L, 296L, 8L, 1L, 
    57L, 316L, 140L, 58L, 24L, 221L, 4L, 1L, 12L, 132L, 50L, 
    246L, 4L, 2L, 52L, 12L, 330L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 127L, 
    10L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 1095L, 1L, 22L, 1L, 32L, 35L, 12L, 2L, 
    68L, 227L, 91L, 3L, 18L, 9L, 1204L, 111L, 97L, 2L, 1L, 24L, 
    5L, 1L, 12L, 9L, 58L, 8L, 5L, 90L, 40L, 3L, 74L, 2L, 9L, 
    67L, 1L, 27L, 1210L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 11L, 31L, 69L, 23L, 
    138L, 18L, 54L, 56L, 5L, 2L, 393L, 30L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 24L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 44L, 47L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 504L, 39L, 120L, 
    57L, 1L, 86L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 141L, 53L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 
    10L, 63L, 13L, 9L, 142L, 85L, 3L, 52L, 1L, 10L, 3L, 12L, 
    77L, 94L, 123L, 98L, 122L, 10L, 1L, 58L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 736L, 
    199L, 1L, 5L, 50L, 5L, 116L, 1L, 44L, 19L, 38L, 8L, 21L, 
    202L, 6L, 1L, 161L, 29L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L), med_price_per_sqft = c(5, 
    4.66666666666667, 4.2, 4.18013856812933, 4.08333333333333, 
    4.04, 4.0354609929078, 4, 3.99032710280374, 3.98897058823529, 
    3.9034045922407, 3.9, 3.88116308470291, 3.86, 3.82308845577211, 
    3.7728102189781, 3.76929674099485, 3.74264705882353, 3.69618055555556, 
    3.69573863636364, 3.6831550802139, 3.66666666666667, 3.65625, 
    3.64189189189189, 3.58374792703151, 3.57142857142857, 3.54471544715447, 
    3.53688524590164, 3.51333333333333, 3.50317316409791, 3.5, 
    3.49848942598187, 3.49444444444444, 3.47619047619048, 3.47401774397972, 
    3.45727272727273, 3.41958041958042, 3.37795612133512, 3.363359030837, 
    3.32738095238095, 3.325, 3.27861163227017, 3.27301279122887, 
    3.25824175824176, 3.25573020153278, 3.19213846480068, 3.16583333333333, 
    3.14713463212158, 3.13888888888889, 3.13142307692308, 3.13016006347505, 
    3.11875693673696, 3.09235253435972, 3.09020229468599, 3.06122448979592, 
    3.05555555555556, 3.03627760252366, 3.03591160220994, 3.02625786163522, 
    3.02142857142857, 3.00148762207586, 3.00066844919786, 2.99727272727273, 
    2.99404761904762, 2.99, 2.9879746835443, 2.9375, 2.91209677419355, 
    2.89135365891112, 2.88281549118591, 2.87875, 2.86536675951718, 
    2.85714285714286, 2.81768034308939, 2.79123951537745, 2.77777777777778, 
    2.77522349936143, 2.7669256381798, 2.7543720190779, 2.75, 
    2.74318396226415, 2.73449920508744, 2.71538461538462, 2.69176470588235, 
    2.68461538461538, 2.66907880133185, 2.66666666666667, 2.62635201573255, 
    2.60714285714286, 2.58534136546185, 2.57723577235772, 2.57512015274212, 
    2.56058508446642, 2.54285714285714, 2.53846153846154, 2.52729693741678, 
    2.50523012552301, 2.50461538461538, 2.5, 2.49951690821256, 
    2.46848739495798, 2.45687994200742, 2.45562130177515, 2.45454545454545, 
    2.44368266405485, 2.43348115299335, 2.43055555555556, 2.41045883940621, 
    2.3797619047619, 2.37634408602151, 2.35714285714286, 2.3481943398692, 
    2.34350282485876, 2.33833333333333, 2.32105538140021, 2.31798483206934, 
    2.31152204836415, 2.30769230769231, 2.30625, 2.30615384615385, 
    2.29508196721311, 2.295, 2.27728787668379, 2.27435897435897, 
    2.25362976406534, 2.24403927068724, 2.23076923076923, 2.22444444444444, 
    2.22, 2.21666666666667, 2.21428571428571, 2.20714285714286, 
    2.20436280137773, 2.19209039548023, 2.17721518987342, 2.16666666666667, 
    2.16666666666667, 2.16388888888889, 2.15336134453782, 2.14445479962721, 
    2.13888888888889, 2.125, 2.11339178955759, 2.11327134404057, 
    2.08571428571429, 2.08333333333333, 2.07594936708861, 2.06607929515418, 
    2.06360946745562, 2.05028571428571, 2.04957102001907, 2.04285714285714, 
    2.04259776536313, 2.03725961538462, 2.03240740740741, 2.02255639097744, 
    2.01960784313725, 1.99375, 1.98915298574779, 1.98426966292135, 
    1.97368421052632, 1.88873626373626, 1.85515873015873, 1.84705882352941, 
    1.84639302474793, 1.84375, 1.82352941176471, 1.75, 1.74705882352941, 
    1.74576271186441, 1.7, 1.67493796526055, 1.67179487179487, 
    1.66322314049587, 1.65129682997118, 1.62018255578093, 1.61895360315893, 
    1.61596958174905, 1.61161966161109, 1.60403299725023, 1.60359508041627, 
    1.6, 1.55765441271482, 1.546875, 1.52173913043478, 1.50738916256158, 
    1.43391521197007, 1.41666666666667, 1.39547413793103, 1.03448275862069
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-190L))
```

Comment: There are two general directions: 1) You could connect your city data to a publicly available shape file (e.g. [from here](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html)) and plot that, or 2) You could geocode your city names into Lon/Lat values and make a heatmap with `ggplot2::geom_density_2d()` or similar. The latter approach would be probably more sensible if you do not possess data for all areas defined as "city" in the shapefile.

Comment: Were you able to solve your question, @Katie?